# while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a php to pull all records from a mysql db, and display them formatted. For some reason the 1st record displays correctly, but the 2nd record that displays directly below it does not show the field name. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
        $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'root';
        $db_pwd = '***';
        $database = 'db';
        $table = 'upstable';
        if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
            die("Can't connect to database");

        if (!mysql_select_db($database))
            die("Can't select database");
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");                              // sending query

        if (!$result) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        } 
        $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))                                        // printing table rows
        {
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[0]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[1]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[2]v</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[3]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[4]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[5]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[6]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[7]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</div></b><div id='column2'>$row[8]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[9]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[10]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[11]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[12]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[13]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[14]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[15]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$row[16]</div><br>";
            $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
            echo "<div id='column'><b>{$field->name}:</b></div><div id='column'>$row[17]</div><br><br><br>";
            $row = 0;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        ?>
```

UPDATED:

ALMOST fixed, but it's not quite right. It is making each complete set of data alternating backgrounds (the class "column2" is grey and "columnn" is white), rather than every other row in each set. Does that make more sense?

This is what I'm using right now, what should I change?

```
$row_num = 0;

$css_classes[0] = 'column2';
$css_classes[1] = 'column';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $row_num++;

    $class = $css_classes[$row_num % 2];

    foreach ($row as $col_name => $col_val)
    {
        echo "<div class='$class'><b>{$col_name}:</b></div><div class='$class'>$col_val</div><br>";
    }

echo "<br><br>";
```

Comment: unrelated, but you must not use the same ID twice

Comment: careful not to use the same ID multiple times - use class instead

Comment: I normally don't downvote, but you have to move on from mysql_* functions! its 2014

Comment: You better use [mysql_fetch_array](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), thats much easier to handle, even better have a look at the red box and change to a modern API like PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I'll swap out id for class and switch to mysqli. Could have done without the snark though, it's 2014, be nice.

Comment: @Johnny Just stick with it. Your biggest critics are often your biggest fans, So listen to what a critic has to say.Everyone else is just trying to get upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should work perfectly, and has more readibility.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        foreach ($row as $col_name => $col_val)
        {
            echo "<div id='column2'><b>{$col_name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$col_val</div><br>";
        }

    }
```

### Updated

Well, I'm not good at HTML/CSS. I would like to to like this if I were you.

```
$row_num = 0;

$css_classes[0] = 'gray_style';
$css_classes[1] = 'white_style';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $row_num++;

    $class = $css_classes[$row_num % 2];

    foreach ($row as $col_name => $col_val)
    {
        echo "<div id='column2' class='$class'><b>{$col_name}:</b></div><div id='column2'>$col_val</div><br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: You're a hero. I'd vote this up but I don't have enough reputation points yet (I'm new at this, obviously). Thanks.

Comment: Don't encourage the usage of `mysql_*`. that won't solve anything.

Comment: @InoSHeo Not only that, but you have a foreach loop inside of a while loop

Comment: @r3wt Look, OP want to print all columns of selected Table. your mysqli version prints all columns?

Comment: @r3wt in your answer, "You're only fetching the first row" => No, OP has fetched all rows from resultset. His problem is he is trying to fetch fields inside `while()` loop.

Comment: @InoSHeo, thank you for solving my issue. How do I make every other row a different css class? They are alternating colours, (grey background, white background, grey background, white ...) for readability. There are 18 columns.

Comment: @InoSHeo, I've updated the question based on your suggestion, showing what I've tried. Almost fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You're only fetching the first row(because $results default position is [0], which is the first row.).

you obviously don't understand the process involved in fetching sorting, and displaying data with php, but here's an example of a prepared statement and a normal query using `mysqli`.

**mysqli query**

```
function getmarkets()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT pair, last_price FROM all_currency_data");
    $num_rows = $query->num_rows;
    if($num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $mkt  = explode("-",$row["pair"]);
            $coin = $mkt[0];
            $base = $mkt[1];
            echo '<a class="animate" href="?p=trade&market='.urlencode($row["pair"]).'" style="text-decoration: none;"><li class="mkt-normal" id="'.$row["pair"].'_div">'.$coin.'/'.$base.' <span class="price" id="'.$row["pair"].'_price">'.$row["last_price"].'</span></li></a>';
        }
        $query->close();
    }

}
```

**prepared statement**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user,message,timestamp FROM uc_support_replies WHERE tickethash = ? ORDER BY timestamp ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$ticket);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user,$message,$timestamp);
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        if(in_array($user, $admins)) {
            $color = '0404B4';
        }else{
            $color = '2E2E2E';
        }
        $output .=
        '
        <div class="msgdiv">
        <hr class="five">
        <span class="user_name" style="color:#'.$color.'"><u>'.$user.'</u></span>
        </br>
        <span class="user_message">'.$message.'</span>
        </br>
        <span data-livestamp="'.$timestamp.'">'.$timestamp.'</span>
        <hr class="five">
        </div>
        ';
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The MySQL extension was officially deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 in late 2012 and it will be removed in the future. Recommended alternative since PHP 5 and later is MySQLi ("i" stands for "improved"). http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.